# Scala & Spark & sql merge lines to generate HTML

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to learn Scala & Spark, I have a "tablaTemporal"  with IDs. In Scala i want to merge line by line a text like this:

```
SELECT '<a href=https://www.myPage.com/visitID_' || _id  || '>VisitID</a>'
    FROM tablaTemporal
```

and i need a  result like

```
<a href=https://www.myWebPage.com/visitThisID_1>Visit ID tutorial</a>
<a href=https://www.myWebPage.com/visitThisID_2>Visit ID tutorial</a>
<a href=https://www.myWebPage.com/visitThisID_3>Visit ID tutorial</a>
<a href=https://www.myWebPage.com/visitThisID_4>Visit ID tutorial</a>
<a href=https://www.myWebPage.com/visitThisID_5>Visit ID tutorial</a>
```

something like

```
val fixPartBefore = " <a href="https://www.myWebPage.com/visitThisID_> ";

val fixPartAfter = ">Visit ID tutorial</a>";

result = fixPartBefore + id + fixPartafter
```

for each line

this is working to export the IDs and i need to merge text in a multiline result (in scala), is this possible?

```
scala> val intento1 = sql("SELECT  _id  FROM tablaTemporal where _id < 6" )
intento1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_id: bigint]

scala> intento1.show(20, false)
+---+
|_id|
+---+
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
|4  |
|5  |
+---+


scala>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UserDefinedFunction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/UserDefinedFunction.html) like this

```
val fixPartBefore = " <a href="https://www.myWebPage.com/visitThisID_> "

val fixPartAfter = ">Visit ID tutorial</a>"

val ownConcat = udf((id: String) => {
  fixPartBefore + id + fixPartafter
})

data.withColumn("html", ownConcat('id)).show
```

Or use built-in `concat` `concat_ws` function

Comment: You can provide constants to `concat` and `concat_ws` too by using `lit("constant string")`. Question is an exact duplicate.